# ReactJS this.state is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside my component value of `this.state` is always null. Here is the code:

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    static: PropTypes.bool
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      static: false
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  onMouseEnter() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className={s.root} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave.bind(this)}>

      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

in console I see only `null` on mouse enter, mouse leave and receiving new props.

Do you have any ideas why is it happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure this is the _only_ code involved in this issue?

Comment: try to remove static propTypes ... from your code

Comment: Unable to duplicate: https://jsbin.com/vurimac/edit?html,js,console,output. You almost certainly have another error happening in your code somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to work through this problem, and found the issue to be that you need to bind your methods to the object. I did this in the constructor and it fixed my issue.

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        static: PropTypes.bool
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            static: false
        };

        this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
        this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    onMouseEnter() {
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    onMouseLeave() {
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className={s.root} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}></nav>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is calling `bind` in the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` attributes, which should also work.

Comment: @Zach I saw that was happening, but thought it might be necessary to have it done in the constructor instead of in the render function.

Answer (score -2):

If you'd like to set an initial state, you need to implement `getInitialState()`, not try to `this.state = { ... }` in the constructor.

Also, the proper way to set properties on the state is to use `setState({ static: false })`, not `this.state.static = false`.

Comment: This is true when not using the ES6 syntax, however when using ES6, setInitialState() is not called. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor